# Nan in summary histogram for: distance in a Siamese Network

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train and test a Siamese network and I have positive and negative pairs of images.
When I start running the model, at some point I get:

**InvalidArgumentError: Nan in summary histogram for: distance**

In some runs it happens in the very beginning, step 4 or 5, while in some other runs it happens some steps later.
The arguments of the model are:

> n_steps: 600 
>   share_weights: True 
>   margin: 100 
>   threshold: 0.3
>   learning_rate: 0.001 
>   batch_size: 64

I am using Adam Optimizer.
The way I calculate the distance is:

```
loss, distance_0 = contrastive_loss(self.net0.output(), self.net1.output(), self.y, self.margin)
distance = network_layers.get_scaled_tensor(self.distance_0, 'scaled_distance')
```

I am using contrastive loss with this code:

```
def contrastive_loss(out0, out1, y_true, margin):
    with tf.name_scope('contrastive_loss'):
        d = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(out0, out1)), 1)
        d_sqrt = tf.sqrt(1e-6 + d)
        loss = (y_true * d) + ((1 - y_true) * tf.square(tf.maximum(tf.subtract(margin, d_sqrt), 0)))
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss)  # Note: constant component removed (/2)
        return loss, d_sqrt
```

And I later perform scaling on the distance tensor.

```
def get_scaled_tensor(inputs, name, vmin=0., vmax=1.):
    """
    :param inputs: input tensor
    :param name: name of tensor
    :param vmin: min value for scaling
    :param vmax: max value for scaling
    :return: a tensor to scale inputs to the interval of [vmin, vmax]
    """
    inputs_min = tf.reduce_min(inputs)
    inputs_max = tf.reduce_max(inputs)
    if inputs_min == inputs_max:
        return inputs

    scaled = (inputs - inputs_min) / (inputs_max - inputs_min)
    scaled = tf.add(scaled * (vmax - vmin), vmin, name=name)
    return scaled
```

I tried printing out the distance tensor at every step to see if any NaN values are being generated. Right before the error, this is what I have:

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

As you can see, within the tensor, the values are all 0 except one value which is 1.
The same thing happens in different runs only the position of ‘1’ changes. 
For example another distance tensor right before the error:

[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]

These are some of the distance tensors from the previous steps that run successfully:

Step 0:
[0.03674867 0.00787617 0.2477202  0.3154928  0.10931009 0.2735154
 0.13083686 0.14834054 0.09842198 0.09132127 0.0856637  0.6076441
 0.100755   0.09179091 0.11605983 0.3297588  0.28090978 0.01025809
 0.12361664 0.11507085 0.06570645 0.0616716  0.12276769 0.12957902
 0.2234131  0.5456302  0.16503233 0.03914422 0.15807444 0.9947304
 0.5870102  0.17302574 0.15670143 0.07926143 0.12775105 0.06380077
 0.5533038  0.7977735  0.22019525 0.07887711 0.18530448 0.12723611
 0.05254128 0.46612477 0.5007302  0.         0.03045994 0.
 0.25195697 0.03005651 0.900458   0.         0.36718735 0.15492864
 0.42535746 0.151013   0.7009924  0.12371618 0.05326976 0.04238863
 0.08139887 1.         0.14789903 0.02012084]

Step 1:
[0.00000000e+00 5.47710210e-02 9.02850509e-01 8.88542950e-01
 4.31583114e-02 6.15703311e-09 6.10682368e-01 9.25455615e-02
 1.00000000e+00 5.41838706e-01 4.48709205e-02 2.73277704e-02
 2.96332520e-02 1.20817451e-02 2.27759629e-02 3.11016534e-02
 6.85849637e-02 5.71546005e-03 6.70421779e-01 6.15703311e-09
 1.96496379e-02 4.62664776e-02 2.84987278e-02 6.15703311e-09
 5.13420582e-01 1.88366547e-02 1.45142935e-02 8.92327540e-03
 6.32246491e-03 8.08481336e-01 0.00000000e+00 5.63631430e-02
 3.69409472e-02 7.36759901e-01 5.46008237e-02 1.17494063e-02
 1.54513204e-02 1.68218538e-02 6.69234037e-01 3.33906822e-02
 3.26752402e-02 3.83973792e-02 5.73891141e-02 1.11822821e-01
 5.12272008e-02 6.93304315e-02 5.14047369e-02 1.80864055e-03
 1.57557316e-02 1.11042978e-02 1.07334806e-02 6.15703311e-09
 0.00000000e+00 1.03809848e-01 0.00000000e+00 6.15703311e-09
 2.19233677e-01 1.49917230e-02 1.25507280e-01 1.75409820e-02
 7.54028440e-01 5.22847399e-02 8.12488422e-02 1.12156458e-01]

Step 2:
[0.         0.01425315 0.6806311  0.63107663 0.00653503 0.00653504
 0.00653503 0.00653503 0.0405196  0.00653503 0.00653503 0.02334335
 0.08763484 0.12318593 0.8585707  0.         0.00653504 0.01887737
 0.00653503 0.78051955 0.00653503 0.02088702 0.00653503 0.03008028
 0.03201023 0.36658844 0.00653503 0.01497512 0.0114087  0.03001456
 0.00653503 0.00653503 0.00653503 0.95640105 0.01957083 0.00653503
 0.08598939 0.00653503 0.49910328 0.00653503 0.00653503 0.02415803
 0.02409992 0.71698534 0.00653503 0.00659794 0.01573122 0.6454014
 0.00653503 0.81859267 0.00653503 0.00653503 0.03296572 0.00653504
 0.07882535 0.2214024  1.         0.00653503 0.00653503 0.00653503
 0.02502085 0.05808342 0.00653503 0.03955946]

Step 3:
[0.01213129 0.01213101 0.01213105 0.01213101 0.01213105 0.01213116
 0.01213094 0.01213101 0.01213147 0.01213094 0.01213105 0.
 0.0121312  0.01213112 0.01213133 0.01213125 0.01213105 0.01213096
 0.55621964 0.01213142 0.01213109 0.01213114 0.01213133 0.
 0.         0.         0.01213133 0.01213101 0.         0.
 0.01213129 0.         0.01213153 0.         0.         0.01213114
 0.         0.01245531 0.         0.01213101 0.01213105 0.01213105
 0.01213129 0.01213101 0.0121312  0.01213079 0.35860753 0.
 0.01213118 0.01213101 0.01213112 0.         0.01213114 0.01213101
 0.01213103 0.         0.72302234 0.01213101 0.5268527  0.
 0.01213123 1.         0.         0.        ]

I tried searching this issue and one of the suggestions was to increase the batch size; however, increasing the batch size to 128 gives a memory error.

I would appreciate suggestions on how to move forward.

- Is the problem caused because there are so many 0s in the distance tensor?
- Would it make sense to always add a small value to prevent values from becoming 0?
- Should I reconsider my loss function and scaling function?
- Would it make sense for me to try out techniques to prevent gradient exploding?
- Should I change the optimizer that I’m using?

Comment: Add an epsilon (10e-12) where you do the division.

Comment: @Amir Do you mean in the get_scaled_tensor() function where I have: scaled = (inputs - inputs_min) / (inputs_max - inputs_min)? I tried that but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: It was just a quick notice. I suggest to find the problem in eager-mode with a small subset of data otherwise please provide all part of the code.